# Representations of the symmetric group with image in a given subgroup of $\operatorname{GL}_m$

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, symmetric-groups

Let $S_n$ be the symmetric group on $n$ elements. The irreducible representations of $S_n$ are parametrised by partitions $\lambda$ of $n$ and are defined already over the integers $\mathbb Z$.
Let $\rho^\lambda: S_n \to \operatorname{GL}_m(\mathbb Z)$ be such an irreducible representation.
I am curious whether there is a way to characterise when the image of $\rho^{\lambda}$ lies in a proper subgroup of $GL_m$, i.e. $$\rho^\lambda: S_n \to G(\mathbb Z) \subset \operatorname{GL}_m(\mathbb Z),$$
where $G$ is some (algebraic) group, for example the symplectic group $\operatorname{GSp}_{2k}$, when $2k = m$. Ideally, such a characterisation would be given in terms of partitions and Young tableaux.

I'd be grateful for any leads.

Comment: Do you really want the $\mathbb Z$-points, or are you OK with complex points? If you want the $\mathbb Z$-points, which symplectic form are you choosing?

Comment: @KentaS I would be thankful for results over any base. Ultimately I do not want to restrict to algebraically closed fields, though an arbitrary field of characteristic zero would be fine. Any choice of symplectic form would be fine.